# Can i use PASSWORD_HASH for login names?

Tags: php, string-hashing

I want to have a pretty secure login on my website.
I decided to use 3 inputs for my form. Login name and password to log into your account and a Username that will be shown on the website. So if someone gets access to the table, he will need to brute force the Login and the Password.

Can and should i use `password_hash()` for the Login name or should i use normal `hash()` -ing ?

Comment: This sounds like it is going to complicate things for you without adding much security. `password_hash()` works to validate a pw when you can retrieve the hash with a known unhashed value like the bare username. You get the hash from your database, _then_ you try use `password_verify()` to check it was correct. So you must already have access to a known value to be able to look it up for comparison.

Comment: Maybe just encrypt the username, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html.

Comment: If you had a separate hashed login name, you must still somehow relate that value to the visible username by a foreign key of some sort, so I am not seeing what would be gained by obscuring it.

Comment: But why is it always giving me a different hash? When i create an account with the same login, it shows a different hash... so even if i hash the login and then create a SQL call i can't find it because the same login has a different hash :/ So it would be better to hash the username instead of the login right? So hackers can't target a specific user without knowing his name. But how do i "unhash" the name then to show it on my page?

Comment: You can't unhash something, thats the whole point of hashing (it is one way, and cant be returned). The function generates a different value everytime because the salt changes on every run. You use the verify function to verify it, don't use the hash function and use the value in the query.

Comment: I understand, i mean it in a different way. when i type "test" while signing up on my website, it creates a hash. Then when i log in, i take the login name "test" and hash it again and then compare if there exists such hash inside the login column. But it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Because the `hash` value is different on every run. You need to use the `verify` function. That uses the same salt that was used on the first `hash` run.

Comment: I know about `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. I'm talking about `hash()` not about `password_hash()`. I'm using `hash()` to hash my "login", now i wan't to check if the input login matches the hashed login from the database.

Comment: please post the code that you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will most likely end up doing is having two tables.

One table will contain the user's data, ie a unique user id, user name, name, email ect.  The username, name, email, will all be encrypted.

The second table will be a hash table.  This is the table that you will use to verify the user's username and password.  It should have the unique user id, a hashed(no IV) value of the username, and then your password which you will use `password_verify()` to validate.

When your user logs in they will provide their username and a password.  The username will be hashed by the same process with no IV as to allow the hash to always equal the hash that is stored on the hash table for that user's username.  This will allow you to query for the appropriate record to check the password.  Check your password with the `password_verify()` function.

Once the username and password check out you have verified that your user has the appropriate credentials you will make a second query using the unique user id on the first table.  When your query returns the data it will be the encrypted values for that user, decrypt and you are ready to display the user's info to the user.

If I get access to your tables I will never see any of your user's information. I would be able to see the unique users id and see that the id matches the id on both tables, but that being said all the values are either hashed or encrypted.

I would highly recommend using the [Libsodium Library](https://github.com/paragonie/pecl-libsodium-doc/blob/v1/chapters/01-quick-start.md) to do the hashing and encrypting. (Let the native php password functions take care of all your password stuff.)  Libsodium is now supported natively on the lastest PHP versions.

It is suggested that your tables and your server's file directories are on two physically different machines.  This is because you will be storing the encryption keys in your directory, ideally below your root directory.  If your server is compromised they do not have direct access to you tables and if your tables are compromised they do not have access to your keys.

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

***Updated***

Here is a simple encrypt/decrypt routine that will encrypt the user name without an IV.  This means that as long as the key remains the same it will encrypt the same plain text to the same cipher text every time.  This will allow for you to query the cipher text against the same cipher text in your database.

```
define("MYKEY_", base64_decode('LoPCPKd8iDxHvb8mATzhhg=='));

function encryptName($plainText) {

  return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, 'AES-128-CBC', MYKEY_, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, NULL));

}

function decryptName($cipherText) {

  return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($cipherText), 'AES-128-CBC', MYKEY_, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, NULL);

}


$text = 'myUserName';

$cipherText = encryptName($text);
echo $cipherText . '<br>';

$plainText = decryptName($cipherText);
echo $plainText;
```

Comment: So i need 2 tables, one table has all the data, name, email, username etc and the other table has ONLY the hashed passwords?
What you mean by user ID? You mean the Username or the primary row index (id)? What is "hashed(no IV) value" ?

Comment: Yes the unique id would be an id that is solely unique to the user which could also be looked at as a row id.  The hash table will have the unique id, the hashed username and the normal password.  The main table will have all the encrypted user data except for the unique id, that will be shared between the two tables.  The IV or the initialization vector can be viewed as a salt on a hash.  If the IV changes the hash changes.  So the username will need to be hashed with the same IV all the time.

Comment: I was looking on youtube how to encrypt and decrypt a string, so i can reverse it. I want to decrypt the Username when the login is successfull. I can't find anything, when i find something it's outdated or i don't understand it.

Comment: Make sure you can use the Libsodium library. If you don't have the current version of PHP you will have to install Libsodium on your machine.  Once it is installed and working study this example.  If you can not figure it out post another question on stackoverflow with the code you have tried.  https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/04-secretkey-crypto.md#crypto-secretbox

Comment: I thought i will make it like this. I will hash the password with `password_hash()` and i want o 1-way encrypt the Login name, so someone will need to type the exact same name to log in, like with the password. The problem is that for `password_verify()` you need a database connection. So after having a 1-way encryption that would always result with the same hash. So no matter how many times i type a Login name it will output always the same hash, i mean a hash without randomized salt in it that changes each time. That's all i need, just to encrypt the login name.

Comment: It can't be that this is so complicated, to just hash a login name. So when someone types the login name it will encrypt the same name and check if it matches.

Comment: can you access libsodium in php

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if i have access to libsodium. I'm unable to use libsodium because i don't understand it pretty well.

Comment: what version of php do you have

Comment: I'm using PHP7 on my webhosting.

Comment: run this code and tell me if you see libsodium listed  `echo "<pre>";
     print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
     echo "<pre/>";`

Comment: Yes, it outputs an array with 60 entries.

Comment: you see libsoidium?

Comment: There is nothing listed named libsoidium.

Comment: Thank you for the code, but could you add comments how it works? I'm a PHP beginner and i don't really understand what all this does. I don't feel good just copy pasting things without understanding how it works, i would like to understand how it works.